# how to check the searchBar field is empty and show an alert before running the getData function

Tags: javascript, input

how can I set up a check to see if the search bar is empty before running a function as it's logging a fault?

```
const searchbar = document.querySelector('.search-bar');
searchbar.addEventListener('keypress', searchQuery);

function searchQuery(evt) {
  if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
    getData(searchbar.value);
  }
}

// Run a fetch requst on api to return the data from searchbox in metric units converting it into json
function getData(query) {
  fetch(`${api.base}weather?q=${query}&units=metric&APPID=${api.key}`)
    .then(weather => {
      return weather.json();
    }).then(displayData);
}
```

Comment: `searchbar.value && getData( searchbar.value )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to achieve this. I've added an extra condition before running `getData()`, which checks the length of text in the search box and only runs `getData()` if the length is above zero (i.e. there is something written in the search box).

```js
const searchbar = document.querySelector('.search-bar');
searchbar.addEventListener('keypress', searchQuery);

function searchQuery(evt) {
  if (evt.keyCode == 13 && searchbar.value.length > 0) {
    getData(searchbar.value);
  }
}

function getData(query) {
  alert("Called the getData() function.")
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="search-bar">
```

To verify:

1. Type nothing in the box and press enter: nothing happens.
2. Type something in the box and press enter: a message will appear.